# How can I list the patches of an installed package in SUSE?

Tags: rpm, suse, patch, zypper

Let's say that I am using a program called "hello" which I have downloaded using the zypper. The question is how can I see if a specific .patch is included into this hello package?

Basically, what I think it that I need the rpm source file (but how can I find it using zypper ?) and then do `unrpm` and check if the *.patch file is included. Is it correct or there's another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download a src.rpm with `zypper`'s `source-install` command.

`zypper si -D --download-only hello` would download the .src.rpm ignoring any dependencies needed to build the package.

You can find the .src.rpm at /var/cache/zypp/packages/repo/src/hello-version.src.rpm.

You can then go through the normal process of extracting the package.

```
% rpm2cpio /var/cache/zypp/packages/Virtualization/src/qemu-2.1.0-260.12.src.rpm | cpio -idmv
0001-XXX-dont-dump-core-on-sigabort.patch
0002-XXX-work-around-SA_RESTART-race-wit.patch
0003-qemu-0.9.0.cvs-binfmt.patch
0004-qemu-cvs-alsa_bitfield.patch
<...>
```

Comment: can I use 'unrpm' instead of rpm2cpio ?

Comment: sure, anything that can extract the files out of the rpm would work.

Answer (score 0):

```
# zypper patches | grep Installed

qua-sles12-sp1-updates-x86_64              | CL-SUSE-SLE-SERVER-12-SP1-2015-1001    | security    |          | Installed
qua-sles12-sp1-updates-x86_64              | CL-SUSE-SLE-SERVER-12-SP1-2015-1016    | security    |          | Installed
qua-sles12-sp1-updates-x86_64              | CL-SUSE-SLE-SERVER-12-SP1-2015-1022    | security    |          | Installed
qua-sles12-sp1-updates-x86_64              | CL-SUSE-SLE-SERVER-12-SP1-2015-1027    | security    |          | Installed
qua-sles12-sp1-updates-x86_64              | CL-SUSE-SLE-SERVER-12-SP1-2015-1028    | bugfix      |          | Installed
qua-sles12-sp1-updates-x86_64              | CL-SUSE-SLE-SERVER-12-SP1-2015-828     | bugfix      |          | Installed
qua-sles12-sp1-updates-x86_64              | CL-SUSE-SLE-SERVER-12-SP1-2015-846     | security    |          | Installed
```

Comment: this lists the patches installed in the system, not the patches applied on a specific package.